# Discord Bot in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make my Code shorter but i cant find the way how to do it bc im not a English native speaker and i cant find the answer in my language so im asking u. (its a discord bot that manages my privat server so i dont have to give my friends the ssh access)

```
//req
require('dotenv').config()
//dc bot shell
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const PREFIX = 'sv';
//ssh2
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
var Clientssh = require('ssh2').Client;
var password = 'XYZ'
var conn = new Client();
//wol
var wol = require('wake_on_lan');
//boot par
var booting = 'ssh2 error. the server is off'
var powerstate = '?'
//deus vult con
const activities = [
    "https://hugelolcdn.com/i/633510.png",
    "https://www.memesmonkey.com/images/memesmonkey/2e/2e7c8b624eb66aa0379ff63f0356bbb7.jpeg",
    "https://www.memesmonkey.com/images/memesmonkey/e3/e3971008ad98286718c12f4f1c4da9f3.jpeg",
    "https://www.memesmonkey.com/images/memesmonkey/0f/0fc831250be89c50245df919f564e50e.jpeg",
    "https://hugelolcdn.com/i/633510.png"
  ];
  length = 5;
//start
var booting = 'ssh2 error. the server is off'
var errmax = 0
const game = [
    '', ' mc', ' mcf', ' rust', ' ark'
]
//rply
const rply = [
    '', 'started', 'Ah shit, here we go again.', 'bb', 'z z z Z', 'SEE YOU SPACE COWBOY ...'
]
//ssh coms
const sshcoms = [
    '', 'sudo docker start', 'sudo docker restart','sudo docker stop', 'sudo shutdown -h now', 'sudo reboot -h now'
]
//action
var act0 = 0
var act1 = 0
var act2 = 0
var timeout = 0
//ssh coommands
const commands = {
        'sv sleep': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo reboot -h now',
            rply: 'SEE YOU SPACE COWBOY ...'
        },
        'sv hard reboot': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo reboot -h now',
            rply: 'started mc'
        },
        //start
        'sv start mc': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker start mc',
            rply: 'started mc'
        },
        'sv start mcf': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker start mcf',
            rply: 'started mcf'
        },
        'sv start ark': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker start ark',
            rply: 'started ark'
        },
        'sv start rust': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker start rust',
            rply: 'started rust '
        },
        //restart
        'sv restart mc': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker restart mc',
            rply: 'restared mc'
        },
        'sv restart mcf': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker restart mcf',
            rply: 'restarted mcf'
        },
        'sv restart ark': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker restart ark',
            rply: 'restarted ark'
        },
        'sv restart rust': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker start rust',
            rply: 'restarted rust '
        },
        //stop
        'sv stop mc': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker stop mc',
            rply: 'bb'
        },
        'sv stop mcf': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker stop mcf',
            rply: 'bb'
        },
        'sv stop ark': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker stop ark',
            rply: 'bb'
        },
        'sv stop rust': {
            sshcoms: 'sudo docker stop rust',
            rply: 'bb'
        },
  }
//msg sys
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot){//bot catcher
        return;  
    } else {
        if (msg.content.startsWith(PREFIX)){//prefix
            if (msg.content.includes('wakeup')){
                act2 = 0;
                wol.wake('XYZ');
                wol.wake('XYZ', function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                    msg.reply('wol error. hmm yea thats a crit error call/write the admin');//handle error
                    } else {//done sending packets
                        msg.reply('server is powering on wait a min');
                        booting = 'ssh2 error. the server is booting';
                    }   
                });
                var magic_packet = wol.createMagicPacket('XYZ');
            };
            if (msg.content.includes('sleep')){
                booting = 'ssh2 error. the server is off';
                msg.reply(rply[4]);
                act2 = 4
            };
            if (msg.content.includes('hard reboot')){
                msg.reply(rply[5]);
                act2 = 5
            };
            //start game server
            if (msg.content.includes('sv start')){
                errmax = 0;
                act1 = 1;
                act2 = 1;
                if (msg.content === 'sv start mc'){
                    act0 = 1;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv start mcf'){
                    act0 = 2;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv start rust'){
                    act0 = 3;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv start ark'){
                    act0 = 4;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
            };
            //restart game server
            if (msg.content.includes('sv restart')){
                errmax = 0;
                act1 = 2;
                act2 = 2;
                if (msg.content === 'sv restart mc'){
                    act0 = 1;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv restart mcf'){
                    act0 = 2;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv restart rust'){
                    act0 = 3;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv restart ark'){
                    act0 = 4;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
            };
            //stop game server
            if (msg.content.includes('sv stop')){
                errmax = 0;
                act1 = 3;
                act2 = 3;
                if (msg.content === 'sv stop mc'){
                    act0 = 1;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv stop mcf'){
                    act0 = 2;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv stop rust'){
                    act0 = 3;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
                if (msg.content === 'sv stop ark'){
                    act0 = 4;
                    msg.reply(rply[act1].concat(game[act0]));
                };
            };
            if (msg.content.includes('deus lo vult')){
                const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1);
                const filerp = activities[randomIndex];
                msg.reply('DEUS LO VULT!!!', {files: [filerp]});
            };
            if (msg.content.includes('desu lo vult sk sk')){
                msg.reply('desu lo vult???', {files: ["https://www.memesmonkey.com/images/memesmonkey/2e/2e00978777e2cd6e504eca19f29e99cd.png"]});
            };
            if (act2 === 0){
                return;
            } else {
                sshcommand = sshcoms[act2].concat(game[act0]);
                conn.on('ready', function() {
                    console.log('Client :: ready');
                    conn.exec(sshcommand, { pty: true }, function(err, stream) {//commandpart
                      if (err) throw err;
                      stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
                        console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
                        conn.end();
                      }).on('data', function(data) {
                        if (data.indexOf(':') >= data.length - 2) {
                        stream.write(password + '\n');//password
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
                        }
                      }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                        console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
                      });
                    });
                    //ssh connect
                  }).connect({
                  host: 'XYZ',
                  port: 22,
                  username: 'XYZ',
                  privateKey: readFileSync('XYZ'),     
                  });
                    //error handler
                    conn.on('error', function(e) {
                        if(errmax === 0){
                            msg.reply( booting );
                            errmax = 1;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    });
            };
        };
    };
});
client.login('XYZ');
```

this is part of my code and i want to have it to look like:

```
const massage =[
"server sleep",
"server hard reboot",
x
y
z
]
const sshcoms =[
x
y
z
]
const rply =[
x
y
z
]

Checking part
```

so i want the whole checking part in one operation and that if it is massage[1] make sshcoms[1] and rply[1] not in 15 if statements i now i can parent them in 3 parent groups start stop and restart but then it would be still 5-7 checks what could be done in one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Use an object/map like `{'server restart mc': {sshcoms: 'whatever', rply: 'foo'} ...}` then key into it with `msg.content` like `const {sshcoms, rply} = responses[msg.content]`.

Comment: i meant to write in the 2 line discord bot

Comment: You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68330617/edit) if you made a mistake

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look into splitting your code into several modules, as that helps with readability, especially for bigger projects.

Command interfaces usually perform some kind of parsing to help decide what to do. Here's a simple framework that's easy to understand and improve/adapt:

```js
/**
 * Array of command handlers.
 * They get called with 3 arguments:
 * - The `msg` object from Discord.js
 * - An array with the arguments (e.g. `['a', 'b']` for '!!test a b')
 * - The full command string without the prefix (e.g. `test  a   b` for '!!test  a   b') in case you care about e.g. whitespace
 */
const COMMANDS = {
    test(msg, args, fullCmd) {
        console.log('The full argument string was:', fullCmd);
        console.log('The arguments are, split by whitespace:', args);
        // You'd send something to the user back like this:
        msg.reply('The test succeeded! Your first argument was:', args[0]);
    },
};

// Used by the `sv` command
const SV_TARGETS = ['mc', 'mfc', 'rust', 'ark'];

// You can also add commands to `COMMANDS` later or from somewhere else, don't need to
// add them directly into the object above
COMMANDS.sv = (msg, args) => {
    // Array destructuring
    const [cmd, target] = args;
    if (!SV_TARGETS.includes(target))
        throw new Error('Expected argument #2 to be a valid server target');
    switch (cmd) {
        case 'start':
        case 'stop':
            execSSH(`sudo docker ${cmd} ${target}`);
            // We reply with e.g. 'Succesfully started mfc!' by simpling adding 'ed' after the command.
            // Of course you can do something different here
            msg.reply(`Succesfully ${cmd}ed ${target}!`);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Expected argument #1 to be a valid server command');
    }
},

// Also easy to add aliases for commands:
COMMANDS.server = COMMANDS.sv;

/** Receives a Message from Discord.js and handles it */
function handleMessage(msg) {
    let input = msg.content;
    // Optionally, check for a prefix, e.g. '!!'
    if (!input.startsWith('!!')) return; // Missing prefix, ignore
    input = input.slice(2); // Remove the leading '!!' (skip 2 characters)
    
    // Split 'test our\tstuff    here' into ['test', 'our', 'stuff', 'here']
    // The `[cmd, ...args] = ` is "array destructuring" which for our example
    // makes `cmd` equal 'test' while `args` equals `['our', 'stuff', 'here']`
    const [cmd, ...args] = input.split(/\s+/g);

    // Use `cmd` to figure out which command we used.
    // You could add `.toLowerCase()` to make it case insensitive
    const handler = COMMANDS[cmd];
    if (!handler) {
        // Wasn't a registered command.
        // If you checked for a prefix first, you could report "Command does not exist" here.
        // If you don't have a prefix, don't report, otherwise every message would report...
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Now call the function handler. If it errors, our catch block will report it
        handler(msg, args, input);
    } catch (e) {
        // Error happened (maybe the user did something wrong, maybe a network error, who knows)
        console.error(e);
        msg.reply(`An error happened:\n${e}`);
    }
}
```

For this example, I assumed your commands look like `!!command arg1 arg2 etc`. Commands are stored in the `COMMANDS` object, and you only have to call `handleMessage` whenever your bot receives a message.

Later on, you could use a more advanced system, e.g. where instead of just keeping functions, you also keep the name, a description, who can use it, ... in case you want a `!!help` command or only allow certain people (or roles) to use certain commands. If it's just a private server with you and your friend, less of an issue though.

Example with a fake Message object:

```js
handleMessage({ content: '!!test  a b    c', reply: console.log });
// > The full argument string was: test  a b    c
// > The arguments are, split by whitespace: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
// > The test succeeded! Your first argument was: a
```

Some useful information, although in English:

- [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) *(the site supports several other languages)*
- [`"".split(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) *(same site as above)*
- [Using `${expression}` in strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (template literals) *(same site)*
- [Custom modules](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp) (use multiple files) *(in English but Google Translate could help)*

Answer (score 0):

You can make a map of commands to parameters.

```js
const commands = {
  'server hard reboot': {
    sshcoms: 'sudo reboot -h now',
    reply: 'SEE YOU SPACE COWBOY ...',
    act2: 5
  },
  'server start mc': {
    sshcoms: 'sudo docker start mc',
    reply: 'started mc',
    act0: 1
  }
}

const msgContent = 'server start mc';

const commandActions = commands[msgContent];

const performAction = (action, param) => {
  console.log({action, param});
}

if(commandActions){
  const cmdActionArr = Object.entries(commandActions);
  
  cmdActionArr.forEach(([cmd, action]) => performAction(cmd, action))
 }
```

You should keep your different configs in it's own map, then specify overrides in the map for each command. Then you can loop over the configs in the chosen command and override them on the main config object. You should be able to get the config wherever you want.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot){//bot catcher
        return;  
    } else {
        configs = {
            act0: 0,
            act1: 2,
            reply: '',
            sshcom: '',
            ...
        };

        const commandConfigs = commands[msg.content];
        Object.entries(commandConfigs).forEach(([config, value]) => {
            configs[config] = value;
        });

        const reply = configs.reply;
```

Comment: Okay. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: hmm the first part i understand but the second part where the Action happening not im having trouble implementing it

Comment: @no_sleep Do you mean you are having trouble with the `performAction` function? Were you able to get it to print the logs when the command is sent?

Comment: my problem is the understanding bc i have to implement the rply and the sshcoms on different lines not in the same line  i updated my code so u can have a better look on it

Comment: to better formulate what i want: I want that when the msgconntent='server start mc' that it places the right sshcom in the ssh part (line217) and the right rpy where it belongs (have to write it)

Comment: i think i maybe got it

Comment: @no_sleep I've edited my answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: hmm not really how do i use the sshcoms and rply how to i get them out?

Comment: @no_sleep `configs.sshcoms` and `configs.rply`. You should read up on [using objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) as @Andreas suggested.

Comment: Yeah thx i have it now i used Mapping i updated the "final" code

Comment: @no_sleep Glad you solved it, and I see you are new. Just letting you know that we use upvotes to signal helpful posts, even if you may not have chosen it as the answer. Cheers.